# Sinatra + Rack::Test + Rspec2 - Using Sessions?

Tags: session, rspec, sinatra, rspec2, rack

It's the first time I'm working with Sinatra and I just can't get sessions to work in my tests. I have `enable :sessions` in my app.

I tried:

```
get "/controller/something", {}, "rack.session" => {:session => "Aa"}
```

or

```
get "/controller/something", {}, "session" => {:session => "Aa"}
```

But no session variables are being set in my request. I've looked around the web and tried several suggestions but nothing seems to work. Am I missing something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rack doesn't support passing in sessions via the request anymore (Rack >= v1.0).  [Read this post for more detailed information on that.](http://web.archive.org/web/20111025134130/http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/332-Testing-sessions-with-Sinatra-and-Rack-Test)

The best way to set a session variable in your app is to call an action inside of your application that will set the session variable.  For instance, if you have a route inside your app that sets a session variable like this:

```
post '/set_sess_var/:id'
  session[:user_id] = params[:id]
end
```

Let's pretend there's another route that you actually wanted to test which is using the session variable like this:

```
get '/get_user_attributes'
  User.find(session[:user_id]).attributes
end
```

Then in your tests, you should first call the route which sets the session, then go onto another route which uses it.  Here is rspec notation, since that is what I use for testing:

```
it "should print out user attributes" do
  user_id = 1
  post '/set_sess_var/' + user_id
  get '/get_user_attributes'
  last_response.body.should == User.find(user_id).attributes
end
```

If you were going to be using the route frequently in your tests, then you could write a method to accomplish this in your test file (if you're using Rspec, then this method could go in your spec_helper.rb or in your controller_spec.rb file):

```
def set_session_var(user_id)
  post '/set_sess_var/' + user_id
end
```

and then call it in your tests when you needed it to be set:

```
it "should print out user attributes" do
  set_session_var(1)
  get '/get_user_attributes'
  last_response.body.should == User.find(1).attributes
end
```

Comment: Not the answer I wanted to hear but I guess I'll have no other choice than to go through the whole stack :( Thanks.

Comment: Yea I hear you.  Kind of annoying but it's not too difficult if you make a method that you can call every time you want to set the session, and it's done with the purpose of making Rack more secure (so people can't intercept the session and forge it who aren't authorized), so it's done with good intentions.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the keys that will end up in `env`:

```
get "/controller/something", {}, "rack.session" => {:session => "Aa"}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you mean. What is the difference?

Comment: Sorry, glimpsed over your question too quickly. This should work. What Rack version are you on?

Comment: That is strange, if you open a [Rack issue](https://github.com/rack/rack/issues/new) I can look into this.